# subdomains linked to different files using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to create redirect to different files for different subdomains, maybe domains in the future. This is based on ModX CMS.

I want to keep url the same, just run different file for each subdomain, passing some data. For domain.com it's index.php, for sub1.domain.com - sub1.php. Also I want to pass some data, you can see it in the example below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub1.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub2.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub3\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub3.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub4\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub4.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub5\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub5.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub6\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub6.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried to `#` last 3 lines, but it didnt make any difference. I've got more lines in htaccess, but they are `#`. Subdomain I create in control panel of my server, all subdomains are ponted to the same directory (`public_html`).

Right now I'm not sure passing data works, and when I go to sub1.domain.com apache redirect me to www.domain.com/sub1.php, thich is wrong.

How do I link subdomains to their php files and keep url the same (sub1.domain.com)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove redundant stuff and keep your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /sub1.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thx for respond, this is what i get: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://sub1.domain.com/`. I've got 6 subdomains.

Comment: Does sub1.php exist under $DOCUMENT_ROOT of `sub1.domain.com` ?

Comment: yes, all subdomains are pointed to public_html - domain folder. Thats why i want to use htaccess to point them to different files. The reason i want to do that, is links (images, js, css) in templates, cms... All files already exist.

Comment: You will need to post your complete .htaccess in your question. Above rule will not even execute for `http://sub1.domain.com/` because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition.

Comment: Thanks but nothing suspicious there. As per your .htaccess `sub1.php` will be loaded **only if requested filename isn't found**. Can you rename .htaccess to something else and then visit `http://sub1.domain.com/` to see what happens then.

Comment: Right now only homepage works, for subdomains and any other pages i get 404 error. Because in ModX I set to friendly links, htaccess needs to be on to change nice links to `index.php?q=54`, or somthing similar.

Comment: Without your current .htaccess what happens when you visit this URL: `http://sub1.domain.com/subs1.php`

Comment: Ok that explains it. When I asked `Does sub1.php exist under $DOCUMENT_ROOT of sub1.domain.com`? you said *yes*

Comment: I see your point, I upload `tmp.php` to root dir, and in the file is `phpinfo()`, and for domain.com its fine, but for sub1.domain.com it doesnt show anything. Ill contact to my server support, maybe there is something wrong with subdomains. Thank you very much for help.